# Delete using PHP is not working

Tags: php, sql, smarty, sql-delete

I am having a rather strange issue and for the likes of me, cannot figure it out!

Basically, I have users who are allowed to upload documents, which are then associated with their profile.

If the user decides to delete a document, the only thing that gets deleted here, is the document, but not the content included, e.g. comments, title, etc - it's as if nothing ever happened - except of course - the physical document has been deleted - sql entries however have not.

mydocs.php:

```
if ($_SESSION['USERID'] != "" && $_SESSION['USERID'] >= 0 && is_numeric($_SESSION['USERID']))
{
    if($_REQUEST['submitdelete']!="")
    {
        $deletedoc = $_POST['deletedoc'];
        $svcount = count($deletedoc);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $svcount; $i++)
        {
            if ($deletedoc[$i] != "" && $deletedoc[$i] >= 0 && is_numeric($deletedoc[$i]))
            {       
                $query = "SELECT * FROM docs WHERE DID='".mysql_real_escape_string($deletedoc[$i])."'";
                $executequery = $conn->execute($query);
                $theuserid = $executequery->fields['USERID'];
                $doc_name = $executequery->fields['doc_name'];

                if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1)
                {                   
                    $docpath = $config['docdir']."/".$doc_name;
                    @chmod($docpath, 0777);

                    if (file_exists($docpath))
                    {
                        @unlink($docpath);
                    }

                    if($theuserid == $_SESSION['USERID'])
                    {
                        $deletefrom[] = "docs";
                        $deletefrom[] = "docs_comments";
                        $deletefrom[] = "docs_favorited";

                        for($j=0;$j < count($deletefrom);$j++)
                        {
                            $query = "DELETE FROM ".$deletefrom[$j]." WHERE DID='$deletedoc[$i]'";
                            $conn->Execute($query);
                        }

                        $tempthumbs = $config['thumbdir']."/".$deletedoc[$i].".jpg";
                        if(file_exists($tempthumbs)) 
                        {
                            @unlink($tempthumbs);
                        }

                        if ($svcount > 1)
                        {
                            $message = $lang['643'];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $message = $lang['644'];
                        }
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        if ($svcount > 1)
                        {
                            $error = $lang['645'];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $error = $lang['646'];
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

mydocs.tpl:

```
<form id="deleteform" name="deleteform" action="{$baseurl}/mydocs.php" method="post">
                        {section name=i loop=$docs}
                        {insert name=seo_clean_titles assign=title value=a title=$docs[i].title}
                        <div class="column {if $smarty.section.i.iteration % 6 == 0}last{/if}">
                            <div class="image"><a href="{$baseurl}/doc/{$docs[i].DID}/{$title}"><img src="{$vthumburl}/{$docs[i].doc_name|truncate:-4:"":true}.jpg" alt="{$docs[i].title|stripslashes|truncate:25:"...":true}" ></a></div>
                            <h3><a href="{$baseurl}/doc/{$docs[i].DID}/{$title}">{$docs[i].title|stripslashes|truncate:17:"...":true}</a>
                            <br />{$lang485}: <input type="checkbox" name="deletedoc[]" value="{$docs[i].DID}">
                            <br /><a href="{$baseurl}/mydocsedit.php?DID={$docs[i].DID}">{$lang318}</a></h3>
                        </div>
                        {/section}  <div class="btndelete">
                        <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" name="submitdelete"></div>
                        </form>
```

Urgently awaiting a solution / assistance.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your issue lies here `$query = "DELETE FROM ".$deletefrom[$j]." WHERE DID='$deletedoc[$i]'";` - in your database i assume the column `DID` (document id?) is an interger? you are treating it as a string in your query - hence the query where clause is not satisfied and not executing...

Comment: @LatheesanKanes MySQL automatically converts strings to integers when necessary.

Comment: have you checked in the code that when your script runs control is coming to  $query = "DELETE FROM ".$deletefrom[$j]." WHERE DID='$deletedoc[$i]'"; line. Have you tried to debug??

Comment: What MySQL API are you using? You're using `mysql_real_escape_string`, which implies the `mysql` extension. But it doesn't have an object-oriented interface; `$conn->execute()` looks like `mysqli` or `PDO`. But if that's the case, you can't use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, it is using MySQL. In my connect file, it uses:

$conn = &ADONewConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->PConnect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME);
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$sql = "SELECT * from config";
$rsc = $conn->Execute($sql);

Comment: As a side note, I inherited this project from someone, and the site is live, but barely functional, so trying to re-invent the wheel without breaking anything live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

For some reason, the connect.php was using write only permissions to the sql db.

Change it to All Privileges and now it works.

Now to secure it.